# Writing unit tests for a class's __init__ method

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I am very new to unit testing and writing/using exceptions. I am currently making a huge effort to learning about best practices and integrating them into my projects. As a test of some things I have been reading about I wrote a simple Contracts module. Below is the init of the contract class which has several arguments that depend on each other.

How would/should I write a test for the init method based on its argument dependencies.

Thanks in advance!

```
def __init__(self, code, description ,contract_type,
             start_date ,end_date ,reminder_date, 
             customer=None, isgroup=False, vendor=None, 
             discount_perc=None):

    contract_types = ['item','vendor']
    self.code = code
    self.description = description
    self.contract_type = contract_type
    self.start_date = start_date
    self.end_date = end_date
    self.reminder_date = reminder_date
    if contract_type not in contract_types:
        raise AttributeError("Valid contract types are 'item' & 'vendor'")
    if isgroup:
        if customer:
            raise AttributeError("Group contracts should not have 'customer' passed in")
        self.is_group_contract = True
    else:
        if customer:
            self.add_customer(customer)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Customer required for non group contracts.')
    if contract_type == 'vendor':
        if vendor and discount_perc:
            self.vendor = vendor
            self.discount_perc = discount_perc
        else:
            if not vendor:
                raise AttributeError('Vendor contracts require vendor to be passed in')
            if not discount_perc:
                raise AttributeError('Vendor contracts require discount_perc(Decimal)')
```

If this type of question isn't a good fit for SO, where might I be better of going?

Comment: IIRC, programmers.stackexchange.com is better for code-review/refactoring questions.

Comment: That said, one idea is to simply reduce the number of ways that things can go wrong. Instead of having separate `customer` and `isgroup` parameters, use a special `GROUP` value for the `customer` to indicate group contracts.

Comment: your two first questions fit better in CodeReview but the third one (testing) I think is appropriate for SO. Maybe you should split your question in two.

Comment: @joaquin Thanks for the suggestions. I have modified the question based on your recommendations.

Comment: @joaquin, there is http://sqa.stackexchange.com for testing related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd treat `__init__` similar to any other (not class- or static-) method – test expected output based on various input combinations. But in addition to that, I'd also test it for returning (or not returning, depending on the requirements you have) singleton object.
However one may prefer to extract singleton tests as the `__new__`-related test cases.

Eventually you will have tests for:

1. Invalid arguments' types handling (empty/not empty strings, integers, tuples, dicts, etc.).
2. Invalid arguments combinations handling (in you case it's risen exceptions).
3. Optional arguments presence/absence handling (default values work, custom ones do too, etc.).
4. Valid arguments combinations handling (positive flow works).
5. Resulting object's attributes presence/absence and their values (most certainly you rely on them in other methods).
6. Resulting object being singleton (or not).
7. ???

Another tip: extracting `contract_types = ['item','vendor']` to the class attribute will help in business logic tests organization.